# Likelihood ratio test statistic and Pearson chi square statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I am studying the likelihood ratio test statistic and the Pearson chi-square statistic. However, even though I understand the mathematical procedures used in each of the example, I have troubles getting some more intuition on what these tests are actually telling us from the data and how this relates to the p-value. Could someone give me an intuitive explanation of this?

Comment: What is the context?